# Server not responding to url with parameters

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I'm attempting to create a server for now should be able to register users.
However the server doesn't react when attempting to register using /reg.
When I create a new .get it does respond though, so the server itself is working.

What also is unclear to me is how to correctly format the url.

```
app.post('/reg/:uname/:teamid', function(req, res){
  var username = req.params.uname;
  var teamidpar = req.params.teamid;

  UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this1 = this;

    UserModel.find({uname : this1.username}, function(err, docs) {
        if (!docs.length) {
            //Username already exists
        } else {
            var loginid = randomstring.generate();
            var newUser = User({
                uname : username,
                teamid : teamidpar,
                totalscore : 0,
                lastopponement : null,
                gamescore : 0,
            });

            User.save(function (err, User, next) {
                if (err) {return console.error(err);}
                else
                {console.log(timestamp+':'+'User created:'+newUser.uname+':'+newUser.login);}
                res.json({login : loginid});
            });   
         }
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: There is a typo, because of `function(req, res)` it is `req.params.uname` and `req.params.teamid`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I edited that out. However, now using GET doesn't load the page and anything else replies with Cannot. It also doesn't log new entries so I'm assuming it's failing to apply the information.

Comment: Just so that I'm sure, but you do know that you can't go to just `/reg` right, as it always requires the parameters given? So it can only work with `/reg/someuser/teamid`.

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that :p @Joseph The page only doesn't load when I use that formation.

Comment: Why are you creating something (i.e. the user registration) with a GET? You should be POSTing information like that.

Comment: @Ben My bad, the issue still persists though.

Comment: If you create a normal get method, does that work? Did you try debugging it with a route that doesn't require parameters to see if that is being followed?

Comment: @Joseph First question: Nope, it was a get in the first place before it was edited. Second question: Yep, and that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why I didn't see this earlier, but you use `UserSchema.pre` at the beginning, however this is just a definition and will not be immediately executed. Only when you actually do a `save` on a document will this function be triggered.

Below the correct, edited version.

```
app.post('/reg/:uname/:teamid', function(req, res) {
  var username = req.params.uname;
  var teamidpar = req.params.teamid;

  // If you are just checking if something exist, then try count 
  // as that has minimal impact on the server
  UserModel.count({uname : username}, function(err, count) {
    if (count > 0) {
      // Username already exists, but always output something as we
      // don't want the client to wait forever
      return res.send(500);
    }

    var loginid = randomstring.generate();

    // You'll need a new instance of UserModel to define a new document
    var newUser = new UserModel({
      uname : username,
      teamid : teamidpar,
      totalscore : 0,
      lastopponement : null,
      gamescore : 0,
    });

    // Save the document by calling the save method on the document
    // itself
    newUser.save(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);

        // You'll want to output some stuff, otherwise the client keeps on waiting
        return res.send(500);
      }

      console.log(timestamp + ': User created:' + username + ':' + loginid);
      res.json({login : loginid});
    });   
  });
});
```